# How in Oracle populate the first field of the first record into function return with a suitable message

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I`m trying to solve task below and I stack on second hint. Maybe I understand something wrong but they want to return record with message if there is no return value from statement. How to add dump value then to my table and return it? Should I use type with multiple varchars instead (any way all columns should be varchar any way)? I have done some coding already and really have no idea how to solve it.

Task:

> Create a package called traveler_admin_package, which can be used to maintain the system.
>
> 1. Create a procedure display_disabled_triggers that displays a list of all disabled triggers in your
>    schema.
> 2. Create a function all_dependent_objects that returns all the dependent objects for a particular object.
>
> • Pass OBJECT_NAME as an IN parameter and return an array that contains the NAME , TYPE,
> REFERENCED_NAME AND REFERENCED_TYPE values.
>
> Hints:
> • Query the data dictionary and RETURN an associative array of records from the body of the
> function.
>
> • If a function returns an empty array, an ORA-06502 exception will be raised. Include code to
> test whether the associative array contains at least one record; if it does not, populate the first
> field of the first record with a suitable message.
>
> 3. Create a procedure print_dependent_objects that displays the array of dependent objects returned by
>    the all_dependent_objects function.

Code I have done already:

```
create or replace package traveler_admin_package is


    TYPE m_dependent is RECORD (
        NAME USER_DEPENDENCIES.NAME%TYPE,
        TYPE USER_DEPENDENCIES.TYPE%TYPE,
        REFERENCED_NAME USER_DEPENDENCIES.REFERENCED_NAME%TYPE,
        REFERENCED_TYPE USER_DEPENDENCIES.REFERENCED_TYPE%TYPE
        );

    Type m_return is table of m_dependent INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;


    FUNCTION all_dependent_objects(OBJECT_NAME VARCHAR2) RETURN m_return;
end traveler_admin_package;

create or replace package body traveler_admin_package is

    FUNCTION all_dependent_objects(OBJECT_NAME VARCHAR2) RETURN m_return is
        m_values m_return;
    begin
        SELECT NAME, TYPE, REFERENCED_NAME, REFERENCED_TYPE
        INTO m_values
        FROM USER_DEPENDENCIES
        where REFERENCED_NAME = OBJECT_NAME;

  

        return m_values;
    end all_dependent_objects;

end traveler_admin_package;
```

Comment: The question lists a 3 different tasks as part of the assignment - StackOverflow is not a code writing service. It seems you are struggling with the first task (please update your question to only show information about the part you are struggling with - the rest of the assignment is not relevant to this question). You are showing some code. Have you tested it ? Does it error out ? What have you tried to fix the issue ? We can assist you when you get stuck but it is not clear at all where you get stuck

Comment: It looks like you're just missing the BULK COLLECT keywords before the INTO clause. Oh, and a check on `m_values.count()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code I finally have done.

```
create or replace package traveler_admin_package is


    TYPE m_dependent is RECORD (
        NAME USER_DEPENDENCIES.NAME%TYPE,
        TYPE USER_DEPENDENCIES.TYPE%TYPE,
        REFERENCED_NAME USER_DEPENDENCIES.REFERENCED_NAME%TYPE,
        REFERENCED_TYPE USER_DEPENDENCIES.REFERENCED_TYPE%TYPE
        );
    TYPE m_depenent_table is table of m_dependent index by BINARY_INTEGER ;
    PROCEDURE display_disabled_triggers;
    FUNCTION all_dependent_objects(OBJECT_NAME VARCHAR2) RETURN m_depenent_table;
    PROCEDURE print_dependent_objects(p_Objects m_depenent_table);
end traveler_admin_package;



create or replace package body traveler_admin_package is

    PROCEDURE display_disabled_triggers is

        CURSOR c_trigger
            IS
            SELECT TRIGGER_NAME
            FROM user_triggers
            WHERE STATUS = 'DISABLED';
    BEGIN
        dbms_output.put_line('List of disabled triggers:');
        FOR trigger IN c_trigger
            LOOP
                dbms_output.put_line(trigger.TRIGGER_NAME);
            END LOOP;
    END display_disabled_triggers;

    FUNCTION all_dependent_objects(OBJECT_NAME VARCHAR2) RETURN m_depenent_table is
        m_return m_depenent_table;
    begin
        SELECT NAME,
               TYPE,
               REFERENCED_NAME,
               REFERENCED_TYPE
            bulk collect
        into m_return
        FROM USER_DEPENDENCIES
        where REFERENCED_NAME = OBJECT_NAME;


        if sql%notfound then
            m_return(1) := m_dependent('NO DEPENDENCIES FOUND', '', '', '');
        end if;

        return m_return;
    end all_dependent_objects;

    PROCEDURE print_dependent_objects(p_Objects m_depenent_table) is
    begin
        for i in p_Objects.first .. p_Objects.last

            loop
                dbms_output.put_line(
                            p_Objects(i).NAME || '  ' || p_Objects(i).TYPE || '  ' || p_Objects(i).REFERENCED_NAME ||
                            '  ' || p_Objects(i).REFERENCED_TYPE);

            end loop;
    end print_dependent_objects;

end traveler_admin_package;
```